# What does "it's a mission" mean in this sentence below?

Tags: meaning

When she was asked how she feels, she said,

> "Good days and bad, you know. It is a mission."

What does this "mission" mean here?

Comment: There are several meanings of "mission". There isn't enough context here to determine which it is, so I'm closing the question to new answers. Please edit the question (using the small "Edit" button under the question) to add more context, either by describing what she's doing, or providing more context from wherever this quote comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More context would be needed to be sure. However, it sounds like someone in a difficult situation (such as having a serious illness), is referring to his or her situation -- and life itself -- as a "mission", meaning something to be worked at and struggled with so as to reach a goal.

"Mission" implies a defined goal, with anticipated obstacles or tasks to be completed, in order to reach a destination or state of success. There are quite a few related definitions, see [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mission)

Answer (score 3):

When you are asking for the meaning of of a word or phrase, especially a spoken word or phrase, more context is always better.

That said, the usage here is relatively straightforward:

> [**mission**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mission#English), noun
>
> 1. (*countable*) A set of tasks that fulfills a purpose or duty; an assignment set by an employer, or by oneself.

From the context, the speaker's "mission" is simply living each day (perhaps she is depressed, or has suffered a tragic life event in the past). This is her self-assigned task.